# Update sql table whenever the page loads

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make the online/offline status, I made a table `user_status` and I want to add in the header sql query so every time the user loads a page the table will be updated with that time;

user_status table is : user_id | last_activity_time ;
`user_id` is from the table `users`;

I added this in the header:

```
//check update last_time_active
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$query = mysql_query("update user_status SET last_activity_time=$date ");
?>
```

How can I add also the user? if he's logged in, check his `user_id` and update the table with the `user_id` and the `last_activity_time`? Is it correct?

After that I will want to add in specific pages a text next to the username (online/offline).

Comment: Don't rely on PHP's time. Instead set `last_activity_time = NOW()`

Comment: Also, you should be pulling the `user_id` from your `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: valid point, i'll do that for the time thing, thanks

Comment: how can i do that @Matt? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the userid in the user's `$_SESSION` when they log in. Then pull it and insert into your query.

```
<?php
//confirmed login, set $userid to the user's ID
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
```

Then your query would look like this (**UPDATED**):

```
// Since, according to your comment, $username = $_COOKIE['username']

"UPDATE user_status SET last_activity_time = NOW() where user_id = (SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username='" . $_COOKIE['username'] . "')";
```

However **DO NOT** use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They are being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: it's great, but actually i have from session the username and i have to make a connection between the `user_id` in the table `users` and the `user_status` table ....

Comment: it's like this : `$username = $_COOKIE['username'];` how can i make it? can you update the answer please ? thanks !

Comment: Updated. My query may not be perfectly optimized, but it will work.

Comment: it look good, but it's not working, nothing is updating, it still empty the table, there's no need for the `$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;` right ?

Comment: Correct. Just use the code below, and verify that **a)** the query being sent is the one you think it is, and **b)** the subquery returns what you expect it to return.

Comment: the subqurey is working returning an id, and the full query return ok but no modification made on the table, the table is empty, so maybe is there a solution if the user_id is not in the table, make `insert` and if there's make `update` ? thanks~

Comment: do you have a solution Matt? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `user_id` is a foreign key, then yes, it does have to exist in order for the update to be made. Do the update first. This *should* return the number of rows effected. If that number is 0, then do the insert.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions:

> This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Using PDO:

```php
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
$qry = $dbh->prepare('
  UPDATE user_status SET last_activity_time = NOW() WHERE user_id = ?
');
$qry->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['userid']);
$qry->execute();
```

Comment: i want to take it from $_session

Comment: @Jimmy this code allows you to take it from the session. eggyal is just using PDO in order to accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like:

```
<?php
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if(isset($_SESSION['userid']) 
    // or whatever you are using to see if the user is active?
    {
        $query = mysql_query("update user_status SET userID=".$_SESSION['userID'], last_activity_time=".$date.";");
    }

?>
```

Comment: -1 for using `mysql_*`. This is being deprecated and should no longer be used. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) are recommended instead.