# Ajax post request after every reload of page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a field in my database which has a datetime type column. I want that field to have today's date every time the view is loaded. Can I do this with AJAX and the `location.reload()` function?

Comment: Yes. You can do this with Ajax. Let the down voting begin...

Comment: and why is that ?

Comment: No example, no effort, the usual...

Comment: ah okay thank you for your big help

Comment: Hi @YoussefBoudaya, you've been here long enough, you should have read the [tour] and [ask] by now.  You might also like to read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Guys you get his point so dont be sally just answer him if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create function in your controller that make update the database time
I use Carbon library its builtin in Laravel and its very cool just import it

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

your controller function

```
public function UpdateDate(){
     $time=Carbon::now();
     $time->timezone = 'Europe/Athens';
     $UpdateNewDate=$time->format('Y-m-d');// choose the format you wanna
     //if you working with model so do model update by save()
     //if you dont use DB::update('');
     $InsertedDate=DB::update('update blablabla set ColumnName=?' where blabla=2,[$UpdateNewDate]');
    if($InsertedDate){
         return response()->json([
            'Status'=> true,
            'Message'=>'Updated',
            'Data' => null,
        ], 200);
     }
    else //check the error
}
```

Then in Route web or API as you working on referre to your controller by post and I hope you know about authorization you should make authorization about any one inserted to DB or updated or select

```
Route::post('/UpdateDate','YourControllerName@UpdateDate');
```

in your blade view

```
 $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://localhost/LaravelProject/public/UpdateDate",
    data: null,
    success: function(data){
    console.log('succes: '+data['Success']);
    }
});
```

Then check your console by inspect if you see True then you are welcome if not contact me and you are welcome any way

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pseudo logic...

1. You database field is likely to belong to a database table row.
2. This database table row hopefully has a primary key.
3. Each time your page loads, you get this primary key, and run an
   UPDATE query on the datetime field to now() corresponding to it.

Here's another resource with possible examples:

[Update sql table whenever the page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778873/update-sql-table-whenever-the-page-loads)